# How to access the 'href' property of an <a> in the DOM at different states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

A test page, served locally:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test2" id="good">good</a>
<a href="/test1" id="bad">bad</a>
```

In Firebug's command line:

```
goods=$('a[href^=http]');
bads=$('a:not([href^=http])');
```

`goods[0].href` outputs `"127.0.0.1:8000/test1"`, as expected

`bads[0].href` outputs `"127.0.0.1:8000/test2"`, surprisingly. I expected `"/test1"`.

It seems Firebug or Firefox is trying to help me by showing me the assumed hostname.

How can I access the host name value, which is added to the URL path in the console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.href` always returns the absolute URL. Instead of `bads[0].href`, use `bads.attr('href')`. This should return `"/test1"`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/4rut1vq6/)

Answer (score 2):

The [URL specification defines](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-urlutils-href) that the `href` property returns the full URL. See also the [documentation for `URLUtils.href` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/href).

If you want to access the value as you see it within the attribute, you need to read the attribute's value via [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

In your case that is:

```
bads=$('a:not([href^=http])');
bads[0].getAttribute('href');
```

or via jQuery:

```
bads.attr('href');
```

The other information about the URL is directly accessible through the element itself, as it includes the `URLUtils` interface mentioned above. So to get the host name (`127.0.0.1` in your example) you need to write this:

```
bads=$('a:not([href^=http])');
bads[0].hostname;
```